# Having trouble adding a string to the end of a vector that's in a list

Tags: r, list, vector, append

```
g = list(vegetable ="carrot", food=c("steak", "eggs"), numbers = c(4,2,1,7))
```

Was wondering how to add another element in food?
Tried doing food <- asparagus but that didn't work

Comment: `g[["food"]] <- c(g[["food"]], "asparagus")`. See `?"["` for a lengthy and technical, but useful discussion.

Answer (score 4):

```
g[["food"]] <- c(g[["food"]], "asparagus")
```

Answer (score 2):

One option utilizing `purrr` could be:

```
modify_in(g, "food", ~ c(., "asparagus"))

$vegetable
[1] "carrot"

$food
[1] "steak"     "eggs"      "asparagus"

$numbers
[1] 4 2 1 7
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `map_if`

```
library(purrr)
map_if(g, names(g) == 'food', ~ c(.x, 'asparagus'))
#$vegetable
#[1] "carrot"

#$food
#[1] "steak"     "eggs"      "asparagus"

#$numbers
#[1] 4 2 1 7
```

---

Or with `modifyList` from `base R`

```
modifyList(g, list(food = c(g[['food']], 'asparagus')))
#$vegetable
#[1] "carrot"

#$food
#[1] "steak"     "eggs"      "asparagus"

#$numbers
#[1] 4 2 1 7
```

Answer (score 0):

A base R solution

```
g <- within(g,food <- c(food,"asparagus"))
```

or

```
g <- within(g,food <- append(food,"asparagus"))
```

such that

```
> g
$vegetable
[1] "carrot"

$food
[1] "steak"     "eggs"      "asparagus"

$numbers
[1] 4 2 1 7
```